# Impala: AnalysisException: LEFT OUTER JOIN requires an ON or USING clause

Tags: parquet, impala

I've got an Impala table based on a Parquet file that stores records of video viewing. The structure is:

```
VideoSession
    ...
    ...
    accountdata struct <
        ...
        ...
        emailid string
        ...
        ...
    >
    ...
    playbacksegments <
        array <
            struct <
                ...
                ...
                playbackseconds double
                ...
                ...
            >
        >
    >
```

I want to get the sum total of playback seconds per customer. I tried:

```
select a.accountdata.emailid, sum(b.item.playbackseconds) secs
from VideoSession a left outer join VideoSession.playbacksegments b
group by a.accountdata.emailid;
```

Impala gives me back:

AnalysisException: LEFT OUTER JOIN requires an ON or USING clause.

Since there's no foreign key/primary key relationship here (it should be built into the struct/parent table relationship, right?) how do I finish this query?

Answer (score 0):

Of course; I figured this out as soon as I posted the question.

It turns out that if I remove the table aliases a and b, the query works. Does this sound like a bug in Impala to anyone?

This works:

```
select accountdata.emailid, sum(item.playbackseconds) secs
from MyTable left outer join MyTable.playbacksegments
group by accountdata.emailid;
```